# What to keep in the Context with Migrations?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Suppose I have a brand new application, that is supposed to use CodeFirst migrations, that lists the `Buildings` of `Cities`.

I do an ASP.NET Core API application to list the Buildings of the `Disctricts` of `Cities`...

My models:

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<District> Districts { get; set; }
}
public class District
{
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
public class Building
{
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What should I keep in the `BuildingsContext`, to enable my first EF migration?

```
public class BuildingsContext : DbContext
{
    // should I use these two?
    // public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

If I keep just Buildings, it will not create other two tables, what is the recommendation here?

I need to display Buildings, but is there a need for a collection of `Building` in the `Context`?

Or is just enought to obtain `Citi`es, and then by "deep loading" we could recuperate `District`s and `Building`s?

Or, viceversa, I need only `Building`s, and then I could recuperate by reference `District`s and `Citi`es, from bottom to up?

[image]

Comment: The context is the heart of Entity Framework - not migrations. You put the tables you need to access in there. Migrations will then compare these to the last migration (if there was one) and make the changes. First migration should generate everything. What are you running into?

Comment: if I add nothing to Context, the migrations are empty, so what is the point of automatic migrations, if I should do it manually?

Comment: @SteveGreene if I look on the win's answer I can suppose the Context is in the really heart of migrations, cause there is the place where are defined. also, if I have any context, the fist Add-Migration will create it and use it, so it's inseparable from migrations, and even defines them.

Comment: Yes, migrations use the context. [Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood) is an explanation of migrations for version 6. Much of it is still the same.

Comment: to note, I use EF Core, not sure if is the same as EF6...

Comment: Yes, there are syntactical differences, but the concept of model comparisons is the same.

Comment: how about what collection to keep in the context? should it be only the root one (Cities in my case), or all of them?

Comment: EF will pull in related tables, but I prefer explicit as in Win's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I keep in the BuildingsContext, to enable my first EF
>   migration?

You need to configure your models inside `OnModelCreating`. For example,

```
public partial class BuildingsContext : DbContext
{
    public BuildingsContext()
    {
    }

    public BuildingsContext(DbContextOptions<BuildingsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Building> Building { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<District> District { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Building>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.District)
                .WithMany(p => p.Building)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DistrictId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Building_District");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<District>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.City)
                .WithMany(p => p.District)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_District_City");
        });
    }
}
```

You then register DbContext to DI container inside `startup.cs`.

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddDbContext<BuildingsContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, you run the migration command inside either in [PowerShell or Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#create-a-migration). For example, inside PowerShell.

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Comment: so, there is nothing automatic, all I should do is by hand? because, if I add to the context a collection of buildings, cities and districts, it seems to build something automatically on fist migration

Comment: another point is that I should list `Building`s, but in fact, I need to recuperate just the `Citi`es, and then I can recuperate `District`s and `Building`s... why there is a need for the `List<Building>`s in the context as your code shows?